# ACF Group Field Duplicate Issue

Tags: wordpress, duplicates, advanced-custom-fields

When duplicating a `group` field, upon saving, the `sub-fields` of the new `group_2` are all moved out to the top level of the main `field group`.

So…

```
group_1
  field_1
  field_2
  field_3
group_2 (duplicated above group)
  field_3
  field_4
  field_5
```

Upon save becomes…

```
group_1
  field_1
  field_2
  field_3
field_4
group_2 (empty)
field_5
field_6
```

What's going on here? I've reproduced the behaviour on a fresh install with no other plugins.

Comment: Is the group field name unique?

Comment: yes the new group gets a unique name before saving